# Cache state of Apache GZIPs, are they waste of CPU?

Tags: apache, caching, gzip

For the files that Apache gzips, are they cached or not?

Or it just a waste of CPU every time a request is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not cached as far as I'm aware. You can [pre-gzip you files and store them on disk](http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2007/12/06/serve-pre-compressed-content-with-apache) manually if you wish. But if CPU load isn't a issue on your server than don't worry too much as gzip is a pretty easy for a CPU to do.